# Excel VBA search subfolders

Tags: excel, vba

This is what i got, it works, but it doesn't search the subfolders of "K:". What am i doing wrong?

```
Sub Search()

    Dim RGFileName As String
    Dim RGNumber As String
    Dim Path As String
    Path = "K:\"
    RGNumber = InputBox("Input RG-Number (33xxxx)", "RG-Number")
    RGFileName = Dir(Path & "*" & RGNumber & "*.xlsm")
    If RGFileName <> "" Then
        Workbooks.Open Path & RGFileName
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide an accurate description of what the code is supposed to do e.g. open each file in each folder and its subfolders on drive `K`... At the moment it's opening only the first file that is found on `K:` if any.

Comment: Hi, there's only one file the code will find. If found / when found -> open it. That's it.

Comment: And like i said, the code is working but it's only searching in "K:\", not in the subfolders. So i know i'm doing something wrong there, i just don't know how to make it search the subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a separate function to perform the search - returns a collection of `File` objects:

```vb
Sub Search()

    Dim RGFileName As String
    Dim RGNumber As String
    Dim Path As String, allFiles As Collection
    
    Path = "K:\"
    RGNumber = InputBox("Input RG-Number (33xxxx)", "RG-Number")
    
    Set allFiles = GetMatches(Path, "*" & RGNumber & "*.xlsm")
    If allFiles.Count > 0 Then
        Workbooks.Open allFiles(1).Path
    Else
        MsgBox "No match"
    End If
    
End Sub


'Return a collection of file objects given a starting folder and a file pattern
'  e.g. "*.txt"
'Pass False for last parameter if don't want to check subfolders
Function GetMatches(startFolder As String, filePattern As String, _
                    Optional subFolders As Boolean = True) As Collection
    Dim fso, fldr, f, subFldr
    Dim colFiles As New Collection
    Dim colSub As New Collection
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    colSub.Add startFolder
    Do While colSub.Count > 0
        Set fldr = fso.getfolder(colSub(1))
        colSub.Remove 1
        For Each f In fldr.Files
            If UCase(f.Name) Like UCase(filePattern) Then colFiles.Add f
        Next f
        If subFolders Then
            For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders
                colSub.Add subFldr.Path
            Next subFldr
        End If
    Loop
    Set GetMatches = colFiles
End Function
```

Edit: this will look for the first match and return the full path to the file

```vb
Function MatchFirstFile(startFolder As String, filePattern As String) As String
    Dim colSub As New Collection, f, fld
    colSub.Add startFolder
    Do While colSub.Count > 0
        fld = colSub(1)
        colSub.Remove 1
        f = Dir(fld, vbDirectory)
        Do While Len(f) > 0
            If GetAttr(fld & f) = vbDirectory Then
                If f <> "." And f <> ".." Then 'ignore parent and current folders
                    colSub.Add fld & f & "\"
                End If
            Else
                If UCase(f) Like UCase(filePattern) Then
                    MatchFile = fld & f
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
            f = Dir()
        Loop
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Wow!!! This works Tim! Thank you! But the search took like 3 minutes to complete. With the old "application.filesearch" this was going through in like 10 seconds. Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: Will there only ever be a single match?  You're searching a whole drive, so that might take some time to complete.  If you only need the first match then  it could be faster, or if there's a limit to the depth you want to go to as far as subfolders.