# How may I insert images into multiple columns from an array using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I developed code to search images from a folder (chosen by the user) and put it in a column in Excel thru some loops.

Now I'm trying to work with multi-dimensional arrays, so it can also insert images into multiple columns. Instead of putting the images inside column A, I'm trying to make a loop so it also inserts the images inside column B.

What I achieved so far:

```vb
Sub ReadFolder()
'
'ReadFolder
'
Dim File As Variant
Dim Counter As Long
Dim DirectoryList() As String
Dim varResp As Variant
Dim shape as Excel.shape
ReDim DirectoryList(1000)

' check if the user inserted a valid path or if he canceled the operation and offer him a chance to abort the operation or retry 
lblTryAgain:
varResp = InputBox("Type down the files path)", "Path")
If Trim(varResp) = "" Then
    If MsgBox("Do you wish to abort?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Abort?") = vbYes Then
        GoTo lblExit
    Else
        GoTo lblTryAgain
    End If
Else
    File = Dir$(varResp & "\*.*")
    If File = "" Then
        MsgBox "The path doesnt exist , Please retry", vbExclamation, "Fail"
        GoTo lblTryAgain
    End If
End If
On Error GoTo Erro

' fill the array with elements that are inside the file(gotta put then into a 2d array with the dimension (n,2)
Do While File <> ""
    DirectoryList(Counter) = File
    File = Dir$
    Counter = Counter + 1
Loop
' resize the array accordingly to the number of elements filled inside it
ReDim Preserve DirectoryList(Counter - 1)

' delete the images inside the sheet before inserting new ones
For Each shape In Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes
    shape.Delete
Next

' loop thru the array and put images into columns A and resize the  column, images and rows
For i = 0 To UBound(DirectoryList)
    for j = 0 to 1
        Debug.Print DirectoryList(i)
        With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i+1, j+1)
            Set File = Worksheets("Sheet1").Pictures.Insert(DirectoryList(i))
                    
            File.Top = .Top
            File.Left = .Left
            File.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            File.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
            .ColumnWidth = 30
            .RowHeight = 100
            File.ShapeRange.Width = 170
            File.ShapeRange.Height = 100
        End With
    next j
Next i

lblExit:
    Exit Sub
Erro:
    MsgBox "OOpssie, Fail!", vbCritical, "Error"

End Sub
```

I expect this (considering the folder has only 4 images):
[image]

I get this:
[image]

Points to consider:

1. The last image has changed because I accidentally deleted it (that doesn't interfere with the problem)
2. There is no way to tell how many images the folder is going to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub ReadFolder()
    Const ROW_START As Long = 3  'start row
    Const COL_START As Long = 3  'start column
    Const PER_ROW As Long = 4    'how many pics per row
    Dim File As Variant
    Dim Counter As Long
    Dim DirectoryList() As String
    Dim folder As Variant
    Dim shape As Excel.shape, ws As Worksheet, i As Long, c As Range
    
    'get folder or cancel
    Do
        folder = GetFolderPath("Select the source folder")
        If Len(folder) = 0 Then
            If MsgBox("Abort?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then Exit Sub
        End If
    Loop While Len(folder) = 0

    'any files?
    File = Dir(folder & "*.png", vbNormal)
    If Len(File) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files in this folder"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For i = ws.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        ws.Shapes(i).Delete
    Next i
    
    Set c = ws.Cells(ROW_START, COL_START) 'start cell for pics
    
    Do While Len(File) > 0
        
        Debug.Print "Inserting at: " & c.Address
        If c.Row = ROW_START Then c.ColumnWidth = 30 'only need to set once per row/column
        If c.Column = COL_START Then c.RowHeight = 100
        
        With ws.Pictures.Insert(folder & File)
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
            .Top = c.Top
            .Left = c.Left
            .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Width = 170
            .Height = 100
        End With
        
        'where is the next picture going?
        If (c.Column - COL_START) >= PER_ROW - 1 Then         'already at max column?
            Set c = c.Offset(1).EntireRow.Cells(COL_START) 'first cell on next row
        Else
            Set c = c.Offset(0, 1)                 'move one cell over
        End If
        
        File = Dir()
    Loop
    
End Sub

'get a folder from the user - returns empty string if no selection
Function GetFolderPath(msg As String) As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = msg
        If .Show = -1 Then GetFolderPath = .SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: It works but I had to make a tiny change , instead of  File = Dir(folder & "*.png", vbNormal) i used  File = Dir(folder & "*.*", vbNormal)

Comment: Next step ill try to make it work for multiple folders =)(any tips?, even though its not related to the question)

Comment: I'd left the "*.png" from my earlier testing....   By "multiple folders" do you mean a folder and all its subfolders, or multiple top-level folders?

Comment: a folder and all its subfolders.

Comment: There are example here on SO of how to get all files under a starting folder, including those in subfolders.  Eg see -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68946152/478884  You can replace the Dir() code with a loop over the collection returned from `GetMatches`