# Insert multiple images in different positions of the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-excel

hope you all are doing well
could you please help me in this task

I need to know how to improve my code to insert multiple images in different positions in excel sheet using VBA by clicking button

```
Sub GetPic()
Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
Dim img As Picture

fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Picture To Be Imported")
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
    Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fNameAndPath)
  
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73037020/how-may-i-insert-images-into-multple-columns-using-vba-excel-from-an-array/73040225#73040225

Answer (score -1):

This is a starting point for you:

Put the desired images in a known folder, then run the code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub fnInsertImagesFromFolder()
    
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strImageFile As String
    Dim lngIncrementLeft As Long
    Dim lngIncrementTop As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    
    'select the folder containing ICO files
    strFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
    
    If strFolder <> "" Then
    'browse for the first ICO file
        strImageFile = Dir("*.ico", vbNormal)
        lngRow = 1
        lngCol = 1
        Do While strImageFile <> ""
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lngRow, lngCol).Select
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strImageFile).Select
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft lngIncrementLeft
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop lngIncrementTop
            strImageFile = Dir
            
            'increments in cells and positions of each image
            lngIncrementLeft = lngIncrementLeft + 10
            lngIncrementTop = lngIncrementTop + 10
            lngRow = lngRow + 1
            lngCol = lngCol + 1

        Loop
    End If

End Sub
```